# Highlight orders with different status on orders page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

On the Magento Admin back end , Sales>orders it then it displays a list of orders . Based on the order status , I would like to assign different background to it , or any noticeable way to to visually differentiate different orders based on their status.

Like pending order have a Red Background or some red tick mark , while a completed order with green background or green tick and so on ..

Proper way or any quick fix will do either

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`, add this function:

```
public function getRowClass($row)
{
    return $row->getStatus();
}
```

This adds the order's Status as a table row CSS class.  Then you can throw some CSS into `skin/adminhtml` to do whatever you want with the row classes.  To override the default background color I used this CSS:

`.grid .data .<status> {background-color: somecolor;}`